# I get error: "throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event" when running any cordova command

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4

When running any "ionic cordova" command in my ionic(4.12) project i get an error saying:

```
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
```

For example when running:

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-sqlite-storage

events.js:167
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event

Error: spawn /development/myBarApp/node_modules/.bin/cordova ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:246:19)
at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:421:16)
at process.internalTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:72:19)
Emitted 'error' event at:
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:252:12)
at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:421:16)
at process.internalTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:72:19)
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

cordova plugin add cordova-sqlite-storage --save exited with exit code 1.

Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

I've made sure that my xCode and ionic are up to date.
I get the same error when running for example

```
ionic cordova platform add ios
```

Answer (score 1):

Appareantly `npm i -g cordova` fixed the issue.